# working with memory only data in controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to work with some memory only data inside mvc controller, so I introduced private property of type _user which will hold current data representation. At controller constructor I'm initiating those private property with some data.

```
public class UserController : Controller
{
   private User _user = null;
   private User Data()
   {  _user = new User {Id = .... ... } 
   }

   public UserController()
   {
      _user = Data();
   }
}
```

this is fine, data is properly filled and I'm properly sent those init data (with some changes) from edit form to the post action

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(User user)
{
    _user.Name = user.Name;
    _user.Pass = user.Pass;
    return redirectToAction("Index");

}
```

and on Index action there are

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View(_user);
}
```

but data remains the same on rendering Index.

what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call return `RedirectToAction("Index");` your application send to browser http code 302 (redirect) and browser call your index page. So your controller is initialized again and it's constructor is called again.

To achieve what you want, you should save user data to database or another storage in `Edit` action and get this data from storage in `Index` action.

Also (if you want save this only between two calls) you can add user data to `TempData` property of controller class and get it there on next call or use `Session` property.